# How to use common code in different classes

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have some functions and variables that I need to use in some classes. And it is bothersome to write same function, variables and their definations in each class.

like I have some variables and functions

```
@objc public class ResponseBase {
private var _messageType = ""
private var _name = ""

@objc public var name: String {
    get { return _name }
    set { _name = newValue }
}

@objc public var messageType: String {
    get { return _messageType }
    set { _messageType = newValue }
}

class func initWithDictionary(_ dictionary: [AnyHashable : Any]) -> ResponseBase {
 if let messageType = dictionary["messageType"] as? String {
        ret.messageType = messageType
    }

    if let name = dictionary["Name"] as? String {
        ret.name = name
    }
}

}
```

Now I have some classes like

```
class messages {
}

class chat {
}

class videoData {
}
```

Now how I suppose to use ResponseBase functions and variables in these classes.

I tried using

```
class messages: ResponseBase {
}
```

By using like this I'm able to access the functions 
but when I call ** initWithDictionary** method from **messages** class then I need object of messages class with all data insted of ResponseBase classe.

Comment: how do you want to use `message` / an instance of it? And please let classes and structs start with an uppercase char: `Message` and `Chat`!

Comment: I want "Messages" class object that contain all variables data of ResponseBase. @rajeshKumar I wan to use static functions so that I can call them directly by class name.

Comment: Unrelated but Swift doesn’t have backing instance variables. The dance with the computed properties is pointless. And if you even want constants **declare** constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're not being "swifty"

Use protocols for setting your expected interface.
Use structures for grouping data.

Below is one approach you could take.
FYI you don't need the computed variables since you're not doing computing anything special. Also you really don't need to protocol:init because why the bloat?

```
import Foundation

struct ResponseData {
    var messageType: String = ""
    var name: String = ""
}

protocol Response {
    var data: ResponseData {get set}
}

extension Response {
    var name: String {
        get { return data.name }
        set { data.name = newValue }
    }

    var messageType: String {
        get { return data.messageType }
        set { data.messageType = newValue }
    }

    mutating func initWithDictionary(_ dictionary: [AnyHashable : Any]) -> Response {
        if let msgType = dictionary["messageType"] as? String {
            data.messageType = msgType
        }

        if let n = dictionary["Name"] as? String {
            data.name = n
        }

        return self
    }
}

class Messages: Response {
    var data: ResponseData = ResponseData()
}

//example usage:
Messages().name
Messages().messageType
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly  their is no single answer to your question **How to use common code in different classes** as using common code  vary's with requirements and architecture you want.

Secondly like your case when you are in need to use some functions as common do not use `class` keyword with it and when using it in `messages` class just override `initWithDictionary` method like below

```
@objc public class ResponseBase {
 var _messageType = ""
 var _name = ""

@objc public var name: String {
    get { return _name }
    set { _name = newValue }
}

@objc public var messageType: String {
    get { return _messageType }
    set { _messageType = newValue }
}

 func initWithDictionary(_ dictionary: [AnyHashable : Any]) -> ResponseBase {
 if let messageType = dictionary["messageType"] as? String {
        ret.messageType = messageType
    }

    if let name = dictionary["Name"] as? String {
        ret.name = name
    }
}

}

class messages: ResponseBase {
override func initWithDictionary(_ dictionary: [AnyHashable : Any]) -> ResponseBase {
super.initWithDictionary(dictionary)
print(self.name) // or  print(self._name)
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, okay by overriding function i can get the ResponseBase object there, so how could I convert this object into messages class object. so that I can use it like messages.name ?

Comment: you can access it self._name  after remove private from private var _name = "" this statement